# SQL: How to Join Tables and get values into single column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to Left Join Table1, Table2. but Flag column has to be displayed from both the tables in single column. Left join because I need all the records from Table1. hope by seeing the below tables and required output it gets clear.

```
Table 1
id   |  flag  |  location_code
------------------------------
101  |        |  444
102  |  T     |  55
103  |  T     |  444
104  |  T     |  55
105  |        |  444
106  |        |  666
107  |  T     |  55
108  |  T     |  444
109  |  T     |  444
110  |        |  55

Table 2
id   |  flag  |  location_code
------------------------------
102  |        |  55
104  |        |  55
107  |        |  55
110  |        |  55
```

I need to show as

```
id   |  flag  |  location_code
------------------------------
101  |        |  444
102  |        |  55
103  |  T     |  444
104  |        |  55
105  |        |  444
106  |        |  666
107  |        |  55
108  |  T     |  444
109  |  T     |  444
110  |        |  55
```

How to write select statement for this.... 
Please help..

Comment: why do you have two tables with the same structure but different values?

Comment: `UNION`  is nice to know

Comment: table structure is same but values are different because... updates are stored in secondary table... but for the presentation need to join and display... that is business requirement...

Comment: as @JamieD77 mentioned..`union` of the 2 tables would suffice..you don't need to `join`

Comment: I need Null Flags from Table2 for ID's 102, 104, 107, 110, and remaining Flags from Table1.... I doubt how does UNION works for this...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.Id, 
       IFNULL(t2.Flag, t1.Flag) Flag, 
       IFNULL(t2.Location_Code,t1.Location_Code) Location_Code 
FROM   Table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```